# Как создать зависимое поле в БД от условия задачи?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, mysql-workbench

В результате работы с базой данных выяснилось, что размер почасовой оплаты зависит от предмета и типа занятия. Кроме того, каждый преподаватель может вести не все предметы, а только некоторые.

Каким образом это можно реализовать, используя Workbench или же MySQL?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вопрос не понятен. например что такое "тип знания", как он относится например к конкретному предмету конкретного преподавателя. У одного преподавателя по одному предмету может быть несколько типов знания или только один. Или между этими сущностями вообще другая зависимость

Comment: Типы занятий: лекция и практика.

Comment: Схема БД правильная. А в чем заключается вопрос теперь совершенно не ясно. Вот это средство, которым вы рисовали схему наверняка может на основе нее сгенерить sql-запросы для создания БД

Comment: Попытаюсь упростить вопрос. Вот, при заполнении таблицы в Workbench, к примеру при заполнении таблицы "Нагрузка", в поле "Тип занятия" я не мог ввести что-то произвольное, а выбрать "Лекция" или же "Практика". Как реализовать подобное? Это очень просто, но я забыл это и никак не могу нагуглить.

Comment: А у вас поле неправильного типа. Вам видимо нужен `enum` вместо varchar, если вы уверены что в дальнейшем не может появится что то третье

Comment: А еще я бы рекомендовал сделать таблицу справочник предметов и проставлять в нагрузке их id. А иначе у вас в БД быстро начнется бардак, один введет 'математика', а другой 'Математика' и это будет два разных предмета ...

Comment: Поля количество часов и ставка явно надо делать какого либо числового типа. А то вам быстро напишут в поле количества "несколько", вот потом попробуйте просуммировать его с "много"

Comment: Я еще не закончил с типами, у меня тут другая проблема) С выбором вариаций при заполнении таблицы.

Comment: Выбор вариаций возможен только с типом поля enum, который специально для этого и предназначен. никакие другие типы вариации дать не могут. Ну кроме заведения отдельной таблицы-справочника, конечно. Так что начинать надо с правильного выбора типов

Comment: и думать надо не над тем как это будет выглядеть в workbench, а над тем как с этими данными потом работать в программе. workbench лишь инструмент, от того что в нем что то можно будет выбирать из всяких выпадающих списков никак не повлияет на то, как вам потом с этим работать из программы, в итоге ведь все всегда сводится к sql-запросам

Comment: Перечитал вопрос ... Если размер оплаты зависит только от предмета и типа занятия, но не зависит от конкретного преподавателя, то вам нужна отдельная таблица с часовыми ставками, всего из 3х полей: предмет, тип, ставка. А в таблице нагрузки ставка не нужна, только предмет и тип. В таблице вообще не должно быть ситуаций, что одно поле зависит от других, это нарушает третью нормальную форму https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0